# Apache HttpClient include boundary in multipart/form-data

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I have the following POST request which is supposed to upload a file. But I can not figure out how to include the boundary in the request for the "Content-Type" header.

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setConfig(config);

StringEntity params = new StringEntity("");

HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addBinaryBody("blob", file, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), "filename").build();

request.addHeader("Host", "upload.twitter.com");
request.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
request.addHeader("Content-Type",  ????????);
request.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
request.addHeader("Cookie", cookies);

request.setEntity(entity);
response = httpClient.execute(request);

int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

System.out.println("upload response code: " + responseCode);
```

any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

It will look something like this:

> application/octet-stream; boundary="----=_Part_7_1666975968.1525905116062"

In HTTP1.0 you can have \r\n immediately after the ";" to minimise line length but in HTTP1.1 header folding is not allowed.